# minimum complexity to find if a number is present n/2 times or not in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory

Given an sorted array, is it possible to find if a element is present more than n/2 times or not in o(1)?
If the middle element is not equal to the element we are looking for then we can surely say that it is present less than n/2 times or not present at all. But if the middle element is equal to the element we are looking for, is it possible to find if its occurrences are more than n/2 times ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking at O(lg(n)).  You'll need to do a binary search to find the first and last instances of the element (assuming that the element is present precisely n/2 times).

Comment: yes, that is what i think. But the webpage where this question was states it could be done in O(1).

Comment: @jairaj What's the webpage?

Comment: That page is wrong. The author's answer(shown in comments below the article) only works if the require element starts at the first, or ends at the last, index.

Answer (score -1):

O(1) does not mean that you can search only once. It is the asymptotic way of denoting functions that are less than fixed constants.

For example 3 is O(1), so you can search the middle cell and its two adjacent cells and thus know if the element is present at least n/2 times or not.

Comment: Stupid answer, please ignore!

Comment: Click the "delete" link to remove your dunderheaded answers